# How is access to private data members stopped?

Tags: c++, oop

I've started learning OOP concepts recently and was wondering what exactly is stopping the program from accessing private data members of a class? Are they encrypted? Or is it just the compiler that wont compile.

What I mean is that unless the data is encrypted. what is stopping the program from accessing those bits from the memory?

Comment: Can show us what you mean by providing a specific example of where private members are being accessed from somewhere they should not be?

Comment: `public`, `protected`, and `private` are evaluated by the compiler while compiling the program and evaluating identifiers (and their meaning). C++ provides ways to circumvent that although most of them are more or less Undefined Behavior. This is not about security of data itself. It's about forcing a programmer to concepts an API designer (maybe even the programmer himself) wants to be followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++’s use of private is designed to guard against accidental misuse (“oops! I didn’t mean to read that value”) rather than against active subversion (“I’ll get a pointer into the middle of your object and read the bytes back.”) You can absolutely subvert private access by directly reading the bytes of the object if you want, but it’s not generally a good idea because if the internal representation of the object changes later your code to bypass the access specifier won’t necessarily work anymore.

Internally, most C++ compilers generate programs that don’t do anything fancy to private data members (this is why you can read them in a debugger) and just raise compiler errors if someone tries reading them.